# length of each string to be exactly 100 characters

Tags: sql-server

i would want to display  the final length of each full string to be exactly 100 characters, no matter the initial length of the name.

Lets say i will add spaces.

```
fullname
..............
Amima Meskin   => LEN=> 12
Jericho Shakoor => LEN=> 15
Umara Sham => LEN=> 10
```

```
user_table
==========
firstname
lastname
phonenmb
city
```

So..

```
select CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname)
as fullname
from user_table
```

........ how do i add for Jericho Shakoor => LEN=> 15 for ex. 15 extra spaces to reach 85, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can CAST it as `CHAR(100)` (or `NCHAR(100)`) e.g.,

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) AS char(100))
```

CHAR and NCHAR have fixed number of characters (unlike VARCHAR and NVARCHAR, which have up to the number specified).
See

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

You could also add 100 spaces to the end of the string, then take LEFT(100) of it e.g.,

```
select LEFT(CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname) + REPLICATE(' ', 100), 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question what I understood is that you have a requirement to stuff a particular character along with your string values to make them all of the same length. If So you can follow the below approach

```
SELECT 
    fullname = SUBSTRING(CONCAT(firstname,' ',lastname)+REPLICATE('X',20),1,20)
FROM user_table
```